# Ivy resolve wrong dependency

Tags: dependencies, ivy

I'm using Ivy to resolve dependency in a project.

The dependency in my `ivy.xml`

```
<dependency org="org.mule.tools" name="ibean-archetype" rev="3.1.0" 
            conf="compile;runtime"/>
```

I get the error message in console

```
[ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]           [NOT FOUND  ] org.mule.tools#ibean-archetype;3.1.0!ibean
-archetype.maven-archetype (16ms)
[ivy:resolve]   ==== public: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://192.168.101.173:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mule/tools/ibean-archetype/3.1.0/ibean-archetype-3.1.0.maven-archetype
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[ivy:resolve]           :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.mule.tools#ibean-archetype;3.1.0!ibean-archetype.maven-archetype
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Why the `ibean-archetype-3.1.0.jar` was resolve to `ibean-archetype-3.1.0.maven-archetype`??? I am confused.

My ivy use the nexus and the information of  `ibean-archetype-3.1.0.jar` in the nexus

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>ibean-archetype</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it could be that ivy tries to find a maven-archetype, because the pom artifact contains the word "archetype". Can you add `<type>jar</type>` to the pom in ypur nexus repository?

Comment: thanks,i edit the `ivy.xml`  
   <dependency org="org.mule.tools" name="ibean-archetype"    rev="3.1.0" conf="compile;runtime" ><artifact name="ibean-archetype" type="jar" ext="jar" /> </dependency>now it works!

Comment: great :) you can post this as an answer after 24 hours and accept it as your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem...

For me, what fixed the problem was changing following line:

```
<dependency org="io.takari.junit" name="takari-cpsuite" rev="1.2.7"/>
```

to:

```
<dependency org="io.takari.junit" name="takari-cpsuite" rev="1.2.7">
        <artifact name="takari-cpsuite"/>
</dependency>
```

I didnt even need to specify ext or type attribute inside artifact-name to solve the problem.

I think Ivy mistakenly takes the content of the packaging-tag of the pom (of the resolved library) as extension...

Both of our library have this `<packaging>` tag in the .pom,

See 
[ibean-archetype](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.mule.tools|ibean-archetype|3.2.0-M1|maven-archetype) (for the library you used) and
[takari](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|io.takari.junit|takari-cpsuite|1.2.7|takari-jar) (for the library I used)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed having the same issue using jira-rest-java-client-core. I had to exclude the problematic dependency, then manually add it back, and targeting the specific artifact like you did. 
<dependency org="com.atlassian.sal" name="sal-api" rev="3.1.1">
  <artifact name="sal-api" />
</dependency>